# Truck's exhaust temperature: how to read EGT sensor by ODB / FMS / Can-bus?

Tags: truck, can-bus, obd

I succesfully decoded can-bus data from a VW Caddy, but know nothing about OBD and trucks.

For a research I need now **to read a truck's exhaust temperature (EGT sensor)**, possibly by OBD. I would prefer this method instead of going through FMS (that is normally hidden into the dashboard) or pure can-bus (a little nightmare on its own, both because of finding the access points and the incompatibility among producers).

Is this parameter normally accessible (i.e. in Volvo trucks)?
Is there any info available on the Net about reading parameters from trucks?

Or could you suggest other ways to read this parameter?

I am going through California's ODB regulations at https://www.arb.ca.gov/msprog/obdprog/hdobdreg.htm at the moment.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked on the net?

Comment: Of course. 
I simply don't understand what is returned by OBD, FMS and which stuff is standard and what is not. I didn't find any university study to help me out with this (using "site:.edu" in google)

Comment: University study?? What about car manufacturers... they are the ones who set proprietory codes ie volvo, mercedes, bmw, jaguar etc

Comment: @SolarMike, you cannot imagine how difficult it is to get this kind of info. 
Sometimes there are studies made by universities where they use interfaces. It is a common shortcut to read what they did and improve on their experience.

Manufacturers are kind of "jealous" of their know how (i.e. the proprietary ODB messages) and don't release this info even after proposing a Non Disclosure Agreement. 
This proprietary info is something you normally pay a lot, if it is sold at all: When I was working with cars they asked for 10-50.000 euro for the Can-bus codes FOR EACH CAR FAMILY.

Comment: so what you want is for someone who paid 10k or more to give it to you for free...

Comment: @SolarMike, we are talking about technology here, not about ethics and moral. I am not "stealing" nor "asking for a free beer". 

I made a proper technical question. 
If there is an answer, ok. Otherwise I will try some other road. 
Engineering is searching for the cheapest and fastest shortcut.

BTW, for trucks I would need to reverse engineer test devices that cost up to 50k euro. One for each truck model. It doesn't look so rational to me, nor more ethical than my question.

Comment: I did not mention ethics or morals - you did and a good point it is too!